# C# are they the same: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes & Convert.FromBase64String?

Tags: c#

confused by the encoding stuff.  are `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and `Convert.FromBase64String` are the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

er... no.  `Base64` is a particular way of encoding binary data in an ASCII (7-bit) stream, usually for transmitting through some other media (email, etc...).

`UTF8` is the way of encoding Unicode text as a series of bytes without having to use multiple characters for 7-bit ASCII characters.

In other words: One is for binary data, the other is for text.

Side note: Strings in .NET are already in UTF16, and there are other methods for writing to files and streams as UTF8.